# Python - Create variables from other variable separated by '_'

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to do something in Python that I think is pretty simple but I have had a difficult time doing.

I am trying to create three variables by taking the three separate sections of the file_name variable, as separated by the '_' symbol. The first variable should be the first 10 digits, the second variable should be the next 6 digits, and the third variable should be the remaining digits. The last section could be 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits long. I appreciate any help!

Here is an example of what my dataframe currently consists of:

| file_path | File_name |
| --- | --- |
| /Users/user/Dropbox/SEC investigat... | _0000886982_18795_2687.txt |
| /Users/user/Dropbox/SEC investigat... | _0000072333_16855_805.txt |

Comment: variables, or you want to extract the values?  What should the variables be assigned to? Moreover, it is widely considered a bad idea to dynamically create variables this way; usually it's better to store them as values in a dict/list.

Comment: Is the format always digits separated by underscores with extension? Can there be more/less than 3 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to `extract` the 3 numbers as new columns:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df['File_name'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0].unstack('match')
```

If you want to be strict on the format (10 digits, 5 digits, 1-4 digits, separated by underscores):

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df ['File_name'].str.extract(r'(\d{10})_(\d{5})_(\d{1,4})')
```

Output (without first column):

```
                    File_name           A      B     C
0  _0000886982_18795_2687.txt  0000886982  18795  2687
1   _0000072333_16855_805.txt  0000072333  16855   805
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function will split a string into a list, putting the splits where a specific character shows up.

```
>>> fn = "_0000886982_18795_2687.txt"
>>> fn.split('_')
['', '0000886982', '18795', '2687.txt']
```

One thing you could do is use `split` to first get rid of the ".txt", then use `split` again on the remainder to break it up.

```
>>> fn = "_0000886982_18795_2687.txt"
>>> vars = fn.split('.')[0].split('_')
>>> vars
['', '0000886982', '18795', '2687']
```

This gives you a list though, not three separate variables. `vars[1:]` will give you the list from the second element onwards, so you could do this:

```
>>> var1, var2, var3 = vars[1:]
```

If you know your "filename" will always begin with an underscore and end in ".txt", you could just do everything in a single step, this way:

```
>>> var1, var2, var3 = fn[:-3].split('_')[1:]
```